# How can I chain functions together in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'd like to chain the two functions used below together to improve the experience of our mobile users. First the `updateSelectedValue` function should be called, then the `handleAddToCart` function. The below code works for desktop users, but not for mobile users:

```
<span
  className="optionValue"
  key={optionValue}
  onClick={this.handleAddToCart}
  onMouseEnter={() => this.props.updateSelectedValue(optionValue)}
>
   {optionValue} 
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle both functions in the `onClick` event:

```
<span
  className="optionValue"
  key={optionValue}
  onClick={() => {
    this.props.updateSelectedValue(optionValue);
    this.handleAddToCart();
  }}
>
  {optionValue}
</span>
```

Comment: Though I still seem to be having some issues with the platform I'm working on (shopify), I believe this is the correct answer to my question

Comment: It may be that the `updateSelectedValue` function is asynchronous. You would have to handle that with either a callback or `async`/`await`.

Comment: Many thanks Don for your suggestions and ideas..I've put it on the back burner for now but will let you know if it pans out

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new method in your class and call the two functions

```
export class YourClass extends Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    const { updateSelectedValue, optionValue } = this.props;
    updateSelectedValue(optionValue);
    this.handleAddToCart();
  };

  handleAddToCart = () => {};

  render() {
    const { optionValue } this.props;
    return (
      <span
        className="optionValue"
        key={optionValue}
        onClick={this.handleClick}
      >
       {optionValue}
      </span>
    );
  }
}
```